# Why does the hyperref documentation suggest using gather instead of equation?

Tags: hyperref

On p39 of the [hyperref documentation](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), there is a rather cryptic suggestion to use `gather` instead of `equation`.

> "the situation for `equation` is unclear, because nobody is interested in investigating"

[image]

I understand why `eqnarray` is not recommended, but this is the first I've heard about problems with `equation`? What's the explanation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's all a bit lost in history, but when using `hyperref` many things that are labeled need to have some kind of whatsit to make a destination in the final pdf that you can jump to.

It is a perennial problem in TeX that these invisible nodes can affect spacing in some cases. In particular, they prevent one macro looking back and "seeing" the last added vertical space. You see similar issues with `\color` affecting spacing (often addressed by using `\textcolor` instead).

`equation` is a very thin wrapper around the TeX primitive `$$` construct, and so there is very little provided control over where the vertical space is added above the equation in relation to any whatsit nodes that hyperref wants to inject.

Conversely the `amsmath` environments already grab the whole environment, measure widths and alignment points then build up the display to insert on the main page by tex macros, so hyperref has a lot more control about where it injects the hyperref nodes.

That said, the comment is old and may or may not mean there is actually a problem with the current hyperref code and `equation`.

Answer (score 20):

I do not recommend this solution either, I happily use `equation` with `hyperref`

The only one I can come up with is this little strange one

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
%\let\equation\gather
%\let\endequation\endgather
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  test \nonumber
\end{equation}


\begin{gather}
  test 
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

without changing `equation` you'll get this warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.19 \end{document}
```

Which is a pain to debug if you do not know that the combination of `equation` +  `\nonumber` is problematic under `hyperref`

If you know they are problematic, it is just a matter of finding them and removing `\nonumber` and replacing `equation` with `equation*`

I'd like to know if there are others reasons